# Hangfire automatically starting all recurring jobs after prod deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

I encountered a serious problem with Hangfire in production, which is happening occasionally but is quite concerning.

I am using Hangfire with .Net Core 2.1

After deploying my Hangfire job, all of my recurring jobs are started automatically which is not what I would expect. Has anyone else noticed this?

I am not able to resolve this trouble, Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give more detail about your code and startup configurations.

Comment: this is my startup configuration, l think it's very common`services.AddHangfire(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Hangfire"), new Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorageOptions { QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) });
                x.UseLog4NetLogProvider();
                x.UseRecurringJob($"recurringjob.{env}.json");
            });`

Comment: this is my Configure to start dashboard,it's also very common `app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions { Queues = new[] { "DEFAULT", "SECONDARY" } });
            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
            });`

Comment: I meant to put them into your question so that avoiding your question to be downvoted. Better quality of questions results in faster answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is usually because the jobs previously failed so Hangfire automatically retries them when it gets a chance. (You can check if this is the case by looking in your database for jobs in the `Failed` state.)

There are ways to modify this behavior if desired:

> If you don’t want a job to be retried, place an explicit attribute with 0 maximum retry attempts value:
>
> ```cs
> [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]
> public void BackgroundMethod()
> {
> }
> ```
>
> Use the same way to limit the number of attempts to the different value. If you want to change the default global value, add a new global filter:
>
> ```cs
> GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 5 });
> ```
>
> If you are using ASP.NET Core you can use the IServiceCollection extension method AddHangfire. Note that AddHangfire uses the GlobalJobFilter instance and therefore dependencies should be Transient or Singleton.
>
> ```cs
> services.AddHangfire((provider, configuration) =>
> {
>    configuration.UseFilter(provider.GetRequiredService<AutomaticRetryAttribute>());
> }
> ```

Reference: [Dealing with exceptions](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/dealing-with-exceptions.html)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,but l have checked there was no exception when jobs started automatically.